# joomla htaccess gzip not-works for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, gzip

My joomla site was hosting on a shared hosting for 3 years and I was using this code in my htaccess code to compress output:

```
    # Compress HTML:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# Compress CSS & JS:
<Files *.js>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>
<Files *.css>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>
```

This code was working very good.
About 3 weeks ago, I bought a VPS hosting with CentOS 6.4, and move my site there.
Now, the server is just compressing html output. but JS and Css files are not compressing.

Note:
My css and js files are loading from a subdomain.
You can see the result and more details in GTmetrix link below:
[GTmetrix result](http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.soomar63.com/4clOIkwD)

I checked many solutions in the web but no success.
Please Help me. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that: mod_deflate was not activated on my VPS. :)